# Как сделать динамический запрос из нескольких таблиц в Google Sheets?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Делаю отчеты себе по фирме. Пытаюсь свести данные из нескольких таблиц. Есть идеи как можно сделать динамический запрос из нескольких таблиц?
Чтобы дата в запросе менялась в зависимости от даты в ячейке.
Запрос такой. И вот надо дату в запросе менять, чтобы формулу можно было один раз прописать и просто раскопировать по ячейкам.

```
=IFERROR(query(IMPORTRANGE("..."; "Касса!C:O"); "select Col11, Col12 where Col1 = date'2018-03-31'"; 0); 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо составить запрос `QUERY` согласно формата данных.

Если дата находится в ячейке `A1`, то для диапазона `A2:F18` будет работать:

```
=QUERY(A2:F18;"select * where C=date'"&TEXT(A1;"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'")
```